# Use Xargs to wait for enter key

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

So, I have a list of files that I want to use to generate a new set of groups of files.  I want to open up these groups (multiple files) together at once.  Edit them. Then go back to the terminal, hit enter, and open up the next group of files.

I've got it working, but I'm using a temporary file to do it like so

```
cat failingAll | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} -L 1 sh -c "find {} | grep xml | xargs echo;" | perl -pe "s/^(.*)$/open \1;read;/g" > command.sh ; sh command.sh
```

Is this possible to do with just the xargs?  Really, I mean without a temporary file.  I tried this

```
cat failingAll | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} -L 1 sh -c "find {} | grep xml | xargs open ; read;"
```

but it does not pause in between the groups, it just opens them all at once (and crashes my xml editor.)

Comment: That usage of `cat` is a [UUOC](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat). You don't need it. Just use `awk '{print $2}' failingAll`.

Comment: `| xargs echo` is also entirely useless as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are the lines in `failingAll` directory names? Is that what the `find` is for? Is the `grep` to match only files with `xml` in the name? Are you just trying to edit one xml file (found under the directories listed in `failingAll`) at a time?

Comment: @Etan Reisner yes, it is directory names.  yes it is for xml in the name.  no, it is multiple xml files that have variable subdirectories

Comment: You are trying to edit all the xml files under each directory (found in `failingAll`) at once but each "set" of files in sequence?

Comment: yes.  I want to open up groups of files at a time.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, to the UUOC.  Yes, the xargs echo is useless. Its an artifact from the second line of code, which is what I (Unsuccessfully) started with.

Comment: As a side note though, I always thought UUOC was a bad term.  There is clearly a use... I think inefficient use of cat makes more sense.  Maybe even clever use of cat considering if someone doesn't know about the more efficient command, instead used an existing tool in a clever way to solve their problem.

Comment: It is a mildly "bad" term. It is simply an inefficiency and complication that exists for no reason. Sure, IUOC would have been fine but this conversation is only about two decades late for that suggestion. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this and just quit the editor when you finish editing each group of files?

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do
    files=()
    while IFS= read -r -d '' xmlfile; do
        files+=("$xmlfile")
    done < <(find "$dir" -name "*.xml" -type f -print0)
    open -W "${files[@]}"
done < <(awk '{print $2}' failingAll)
```

Assuming you don't want to have to quit the editor and assuming it can take a new set of files via a subsequent call to `open` then the following might also work:

```
while IFS= read -u 3 -r dir; do
    files=()
    while IFS= read -r -d '' xmlfile; do
        files+=("$xmlfile")
    done < <(find "$dir" -name "*.xml" -type f -print0)
    open "${files[@]}"
    read
done 3< <(awk '{print $2}' failingAll)
```

Comment: That opens up a text file with the names of the xml files.  Then , I dont know how to cycle through the groups

Comment: Ok, now it opens the files.  how do I open the next set of files?

Comment: Like I said in the answer: "just quit the editor when you finish editing each group of files".

Comment: Ah, i didnt see that.  Ok.  Not quite what I had in mind, becuase Oxygen XML Editor takes a bit to open, but it does the trick.  Do you know why putting a `read` after open doesn't pause?

Comment: How were you intending for this to work? How were you expecting to dump all the open files from the editor and feed it new ones? Can you close all the open files and then just call "open" again to feed it a new batch of files?

Comment: Yup, Oxygen has tabs.  So I can close all of the tabs then go back to the terminal, hit enter, then it would pop open 4 new tabs.  Unfortunately, at this moment I don't see a way to do it with the tools at hand.

Comment: Did you try my last edit? I think it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In light of Etan Reisner's answer, I found this also works

`cat failingAll | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I {} -L 1 sh -c "find {} | grep xml | xargs open -W"`

But it doesn't quite do what I wanted either which is wait for an enter.  I believe its because xargs keeps feeding it the next line which breaks the `read` command.